# urllib2 opener providing wrong charset

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, urllib2

When I open the url and read it, I can't recognize it. But when I check the content header it says it is encoded as utf-8. So I tried to convert it to unicode and it complained UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128) using unicode().

.encode("utf-8") produces
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

.decode("utf-8") produced
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte.

I have tried everything I can come up with(I'm not that good at encodings)

I would be happy if I could get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: HTTP headers can be wrong - look for a meta tag in the HTML itself specifying the HTML. It might be Latin-1 (`.decode('latin-1')`).

Comment: Tried that. And I'm quite sure it's utf-8 since chrome sais so when I visit the site.

Comment: If your stream is really utf8-encoded, `.decode("utf-8")` will work. So, you must be mistaken about something. Can you post the URL (or: a URL) that's giving you trouble?

Comment: Could you create a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem e.g., [print-page-info.py](https://gist.github.com/fa9e9efc83a53df02e29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common mistake. The server sends gzipped stream.

You should unpack it first:

```
response = opener.open(self.__url, data)
if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    buf = StringIO.StringIO( response.read())
    gzip_f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
    content = gzip_f.read()
else:
    content = response.read()
```

Comment: I figured it out. But I'll accept this as an answer so others don't make my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

The header is probably wrong. Check out [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

EDIT: Thinking more about it -- my money is on the contents being gzipped. I believe some of Python's various URL-opening modules/classes/etc will ungzip, while others won't.

Comment: It didn't find any encoding :(

Comment: Assuming a browser renders it properly, it probably can tell you the encoding. Is it possible the data is gzip'ed? I've hit that before too.

Comment: I don't think so. I could try unzip it.