# twitter trends api UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: unexpected code byte

Tags: twitter

I am trying to follow the sample code of the book "Mining the social web", 1-3.

I know its old so I follow the new sample from the web page [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/1592859)

BUT, SOMETIMES, I will suffer a Error info when I implement the code:

```
[ trend.decode('utf-8') for trend in world_trends()[0]['trends'] ]
```

And the error info is like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/twitter/api.py", line 167, in __call__
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/twitter/api.py", line 173, in _handle_response
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: unexpected code byte
```

It doesnt always happen, but I think no programmer likes such a "random" case.

So could anyone help me on this issue? Whats the problem and how I can solve this?

Great thanks~

Comment: I'm seeing this in a library using python Requests. The `0x8b` comes from the gzip header: `1F 8B 08`.  Something is missing the fact that this is gzip-compressed data.

Comment: Update: This was due to [bug 2561 of requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2561).

Answer (score 26):

`byte 0x8b in position 1` usually signals that the data stream is gzipped. For similar problems, see [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/366) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445627/urllib2-opener-providing-wrong-charset).

To unzip the data stream:

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO(<response object>.content)
gzip_f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
content = gzip_f.read()
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Helped me discover that I had inadvertently gzipped some files that weren't meant to be gzipped.

Answer (score 1):

By default decode() will throw an error if it encounters a byte that it doesn't know how to decode.

You can use `trend.decode('utf-8', 'replace')` or `trend.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` to not throw an error and silently ignore it.

[Documentation on decode() here.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)