# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 0: invalid start byte django

Tags: python, django, string, byte, createfile

so I have a variable contains with bytes and I want to write it to text and download it. but to use write, it's must in bytes. so how to make from bytes to string?

now I get an error like this. I tried to decode it, but it could not works.

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 0: invalid start byte

here's the code:

```
def create_file(f):
    print(f) #f = b'\x8b\x86pJ'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/plain")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.txt'

    filename = f
    print(filename) # filename = b'\x8b\x86pJ'
    download = filename.decode('utf-8')
    response.write(download)
    print(response)

    return response
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [twitter trends api UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: unexpected code byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072705/twitter-trends-api-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8b-in-po)

Comment: no, i don't open anything but just pass bytes @TharunK

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
def create_file(f):
    print(f) #f = b'\x8b\x86pJ'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/plain")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.txt'

    filename = f
    print(filename) # filename = b'\x8b\x86pJ'
    download = filename.decode('latin-1')
    response.write(download)
    print(response)

    return response
```

Comment: i got error : 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'decode'