# UnicodeDecodeError downloading HTML using Python

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I've just started to learn Python, but when I want to write a tool to help me download the online book "Learn Vimscript The Hard Way", I have a problem.

This is my code; the version is `py3.5`:

```
#coding: utf-8
import urllib.request
import re

url = 'http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com'
name = '/chapters/16.html'
while(len(name) != 0):
    url1 = url + name 
    print(url1)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
    vim = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    address = "/Users/zhangzhimin/learnvimthehardway/" + name[-2:] + ".html"
    with open(address, "w") as f:
        f.write(vim)
    print("%s finish" % name)
    x = re.findall('''<a class="next" href="(.+?)"''', vim)
    name = x[0]
```

This is the result:

```
:!python3 test.py
http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/16.html
/chapters/16.html finish
http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/17.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    vim = response.read().decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I don't know why this happens: I can download chapter 16 and decode it but I can't do the same thing for chapter 17.

Comment: Is the webpage you dowliading actally encoded in utf-8?

Comment: byte 0x8b in position 1 usually signals that the data stream is gzipped. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13483961)

Comment: why do you decode? open the file to write as bytes and just write the bytes you got. oh, I see, you parse the file later..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib2 opener providing wrong charset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445627/urllib2-opener-providing-wrong-charset)

Comment: Consider using `requests`: the library transparently decodes `transfer-encoding`. And yes, [an HTML parser to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem, in fact, everything in my code is ok except
considering `gzip`, I should thinks the guy who remind me that :

> byte 0x8b in position 1 usually signals that the data stream is gzipped.

After I use gzip module in my code, everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Please see example that works:

```
import urllib2
import re

name = '/chapters/16.html'
url = 'http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com'
while len(name) > 0:
    url1 = url + name
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url1)
    data = response.read()
    address = './vim/' + name[-7:]
    with open(address, 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(data)
    x = re.findall('''<a class="next" href="(.+?)"''', data)
    if x:
        name = x[0]
    else:
        break
```

I am using Python 2.7.10 though. 
This code downloads all chapters in html format from the url you specified. 
Notes: replace './vim/' (current dir + vim) for your directory; I used name[-7:], which is last 7 chars, like '16.html' and so on. Conditional 'if' (if x: ...) precludes 'index out of range' error.

Comment: This works for you in Python 2.7 because you're taking the encoded HTML and writing it straight to disk without decoding. Your `str()` around `response.read()` is unnecessary.